# Segue does not trigger in tab bar app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I'm using storyboard and XCode 4.3 to create an app that has a tab bar as root view. Even though my app has other segues that work just fine, one of them just does not trigger. It's supposed to trigger when the third item of the tab is selected. The only thing I can see is that the tab bar actually loads the new view, but no information is passed.

The connections on Storyboard are as follow : Root View controller (Tab bar) -> Navigation Controller -> CapitolDetailViewController (which has a push segue from another view controller)

I've tried many changes in the connections, code, etc. But it just doesn't trigger this segue. I tried to change the code in my AppDelegate to add the new controllers that were missing. The code for my applicationDidFinishLaunching is the following:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];


NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

    tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;


    UINavigationController *view1 = [[tabBarController viewControllers]    objectAtIndex:0];
    UINavigationController *view2 = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
    UINavigationController *view3 = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2];

    SCDMasterViewController *view11 = [[view1 viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    view11.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;    

    SerieDetailViewController *view22 = [[view2 viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

    CapitolDetailViewController *view33 = [[view3 viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];


    return YES;
```

**Where "SerieDetailViewController" is the one that should pass the information when the 3rd item is selected, and "CapitolDetailViewController" is the one that should receive it.**

Code for my segue: (it doesn't even enter the segue, de NSLOG never shows up)

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {


    NSLog(@"Entra segue");


    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mostraCapitol"]) {



        NSString *nom = @"";

        nom= serieName;

        CapitolDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        destViewController.serieName2 = nom; 

    }
}
```

Anyone knows what is wrong?

**UPDATE**: even though I received an answer that helped me to correct some compilation errors, the problem is still there. If I click the tab bar item, it loads an empty view. It never calls the segue. It looks like the tab bar items and the view controllers are not attached.

Comment: check my edited answer. hope this edit would help you.

Comment: The problem might be that you hooked your Bar Button Item instead of the button. I was having this problem and I was able to fix that. Use your Document Outline to select the button that is contained in the Bar Button Item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking the segue method that does not work. Make sure your identifier for the segue in the storyboard mach the one in your class. From the look of your code and all the comments it seems that your code is fine and should work. The only place that might give you an issue would be different identifiers for the segue in storyboard. I hope this resolves your issue my friend.

Edit:

well i don't know if this works for you but i have a different approach in setting up the core data in tab bar app. in .h file of the delegate almost everything is generic, in .m particularly `applicationdidfinishwithoption` i use index number in order to sort the views in view controller that i add to tab bar. i hope this helps, here is the code i use.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[self setupFetchedResultsController];

if (![[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] > 0 ) {
NSLog(@"!!!!! ~~> There's nothing in the database so defaults will be inserted");
[self importCoreDataDefaultRoles];
}
else {
NSLog(@"There's stuff in the database so skipping the import of default data");    
}

// The Tab Bar
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

// The Two Navigation Controllers attached to the Tab Bar (At Tab Bar Indexes 0 and 1)
 UINavigationController *view1 = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
UINavigationController *view2 = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];

View1 *view1 = [[view1nav viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
personsTVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;    

View2 *view2 = [[view2nav viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
rolesTVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

return YES;
}
```

by using index numbers i was able to achieve the same scenario without any error and for the start up view i used a child that i plugged in as initial modal view. hope this helps you. in my case core data was to be added to multiple tabs, i do not know if you have the same need.

EDIT 1

here is my `Appdelegate.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator   *persistentStoreCoordinator;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@end
```

and here is the `app delegate.m`

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "PersonsTVC.h"
#import "RolesTVC.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = __fetchedResultsController;

- (void)insertRoleWithRoleName:(NSString *)roleName
{
Role *role = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Role"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

role.name = roleName;

[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
}

- (void)importCoreDataDefaultRoles {

NSLog(@"Importing Core Data Default Values for Roles...");
[self insertRoleWithRoleName:@"Player 1"];
[self insertRoleWithRoleName:@"Player 2"];
[self insertRoleWithRoleName:@"Player 3"];
[self insertRoleWithRoleName:@"Player 4"];
[self insertRoleWithRoleName:@"Player 5"];
[self insertRoleWithRoleName:@"Player 6"];
[self insertRoleWithRoleName:@"Player 7"];
[self insertRoleWithRoleName:@"Player 8"];
[self insertRoleWithRoleName:@"Player 9"];
[self insertRoleWithRoleName:@"Player 10"];
[self insertRoleWithRoleName:@"Player 11"];
[self insertRoleWithRoleName:@"Player 12"];
NSLog(@"Importing Core Data Default Values for Roles Completed!");
}
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
// 1 - Decide what Entity you want
NSString *entityName = @"Role"; // Put your entity name here
NSLog(@"Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entityName);

// 2 - Request that Entity
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

// 3 - Filter it if you want
//request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Person.name = Blah"];

// 4 - Sort it if you want
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor   sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"
                                                                             ascending:YES
                                                                                selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
// 5 - Fetch it
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]    initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                  managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                  sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                           cacheName:nil];
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[self setupFetchedResultsController];

if (![[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] > 0 ) {
NSLog(@"!!!!! ~~> There's nothing in the database so defaults will be inserted");
[self importCoreDataDefaultRoles];
}
else {
NSLog(@"There's stuff in the database so skipping the import of default data");    
}

// The Tab Bar
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

// The Two Navigation Controllers attached to the Tab Bar (At Tab Bar Indexes 0 and 1)
UINavigationController *personsTVCnav = [[tabBarController viewControllers]  objectAtIndex:0];
UINavigationController *rolesTVCnav = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];

// The Persons Table View Controller (First Nav Controller Index 0)
PersonsTVC *personsTVC = [[personsTVCnav viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
personsTVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;    

// The Roles Table View Controller (Second Nav Controller Index 0)
RolesTVC *rolesTVC = [[rolesTVCnav viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
rolesTVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

//NOTE: Be very careful to change these indexes if you change the tab order

// Override point for customization after application launch.
// UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
// RolesTVC *controller = (RolesTVC *)navigationController.topViewController;
// controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
[self saveContext];
}

- (void)saveContext
{
NSError *error = nil;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
if (managedObjectContext != nil)
{
if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error])
{
    /*
     Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

     abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not  use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
     */
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
} 
}
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
if (__managedObjectContext != nil)
{
return __managedObjectContext;
}

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil)
{
__managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
}
return __managedObjectContext;
}
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
if (__managedObjectModel != nil)
{
return __managedObjectModel;
}
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
__managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
return __managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
{
return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]    URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"StaffManager.sqlite"];

NSError *error = nil;
__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]    initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];


NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],    NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType   configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
{
NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
abort();
}    

return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory


- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

@end
```

now bare in mind that i use both classes for for data entities and declared the managed objects in both classes. one thing is for sure when using core data your initial view has to have the managed objects. if this does not help you then i sugest you can take a look at tim roadley's core data tutorial or paul hagurty's stanford core data class. if you need a whole project to look at let me know and ill try to get something together and place a link so you can download it, but i believe if you have created a proper model and are using the right methods in app delegate similar to what i did, it should work. hope this helps you my friend.

Comment: I've checked the identifier multiple times. The names match. The compilation error is still there, so now I can't even see if any changes work.

Comment: Ok so I copied that piece of code (which is basically very similar to what I had, except for the indexes) and the app crashes. I get the same message I was getting before "[UIViewController setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance". The breakpoint stops in my main but the last line of code executed is "rolesTVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;", so it doesn't even execute the return sentence. Is it possible that the error is somewhere else? Because I have that property declared in my controller and the @synthesize and everything.

Comment: I added the code for the main just in case it provides any information

Comment: RolesTVC is the name of the class I use for defining the role of the players in a simulated environment for my app. In my scenario both personsTVC class and RolesTVC class has managed objects declared in them so these entities can talk to each other. I don't know your data structure and what have you defined as in your core data. But you need to change the RolesTVC and personsTVC to the name of the classes you have in your tab bar. The real code has the name of the classes in there. I will put the code I used in my app as it is in the next edit of my answer so you can see what I did.

Comment: Yes I Know ... I obviously didn't put that name, I referred to that so that you could understand which line I was talking about. But the app compiles and crashes like I said.

Comment: I checked your code and I have the exact same properties declared, in the same way (the only difference is that I add my attributes somewhere else) . I don't know why it doesn't work, maybe the problem is somewhere else ... I'll check these tutorials although I already followed ray wenderlich's one and they must be more or less the same. Thanks

Comment: I deleted adding the second view controller as a self managed object, and now the app LOADS. Now I have the problem that the segue does not trigger (as it happened to me before I added all the view controllers to the tabs). Isn't a segue supposed to trigger automatically?

Comment: Not automatically. You can programer it as you already know or use the storyboard and connect it manually and use the option modal. Both cases should work if there is no issues with identifiers. Programically in prepare for seague, manually with modal or push depending to your structure.

Comment: I have used storyboard to link the two views with a push segue, and then I added in the view controller the prepare segue method (the code for that is in my question). The name of the segue matches with the identifier in storyboard. Nevertheless it doesn't even enter the segue :S I don't know why. I have other segue which works perfectly, and I have followed the same steps, but the method is never called.

Answer (score 0):

check this sample iPhone code may be its helpful for you

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
//  Get a reference to our detail view
PicturelistDetail *pld = (PicturelistDetail *)[segue destinationViewController];

//  Pass the managed object context to the destination view controller
pld.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;

//  If we are editing  we need to pass some stuff, so check the segue title first
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"EditPicture"])
{
    //  Get the row we selected to view
    NSInteger selectedIndex = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];

    //  Pass the object from the table that we want to view
    pld.currentPicture = [pictureListData objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
}
}
```

pls change it to your code and try it.

declare the property in view controller

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

Comment: My segue is just like that. My actual problem is the compilation error in "viewController1.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext" . That property is already declared in the view controller :( It worked before I changed it from "SCDMasterViewController *controller = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];" to what I have now. Don't know why

Comment: UINavigationController *navCont=(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    
    PictureListMainTable *rootView =(PictureListMainTable *)[[navCont viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
    rootView.managedObjectContext=self.managedObjectContext;
    
[window addSUbview:tabBarController.view] pls check this coding in AppDelegate

Comment: It was there from the beginning.

Comment: I tried that and the app couldn't load. I added a breakpoint and apparently it stops here : rootView.managedObjectContext=self.managedObjectContext; and the error I get is "[UINavigationController setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you need to set a property inside 'SCDMasterViewController' called managedObjectContext(I would recommend a different name).

the error is saying that the property has not been declared.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That property is declared there. I used to be able to access it before I changed the code in the AppDelegate, so I'm not sure about that.